# django-nvd3 chart.tooltipContent is not a function

Tags: javascript, python, django, nvd3.js

I' trying to use the pie chart example here at [django-nvd3-doc](http://django-nvd3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html#example-how-to-create-a-piechart) and I've included the js libraries proceeded with the tutorial but the chart wont be rendered and following js error is displayed

```
TypeError: chart.tooltipContent is not a function
<anonymous>
 test:23
a.render/c()
```

HTML OUTPUT:
 `

```
<head>
    <link media="all" href="/static/nvd3/build/nv.d3.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/static/d3/d3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/static/nvd3/build/nv.d3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>




    <script>



data_piechart_container=[{"values": [{"value": 52, "label": "Apple"}, {"value": 48, "label": "Apricot"}, {"value": 160, "label": "Avocado"}, {"value": 94, "label": "Banana"}, {"value": 75, "label": "Boysenberries"}, {"value": 71, "label": "Blueberries"}, {"value": 490, "label": "Dates"}, {"value": 82, "label": "Grapefruit"}, {"value": 46, "label": "Kiwi"}, {"value": 17, "label": "Lemon"}], "key": "Serie 1"}];

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.pieChart();
    chart.margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 20, left: 60});
    var datum = data_piechart_container[0].values;

    chart.color(d3.scale.category20().range());

chart.tooltipContent(function(key, y, e, graph) {
      var x = String(key);
          var y = String(graph.point.y);

          tooltip_str = '<center><b>'+x+'</b></center>' + y;
          return tooltip_str;
          });
    chart.showLabels(true);

        chart.donut(false);

chart.showLegend(true);




    chart
        .x(function(d) { return d.label })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value });


    chart.height(450);


        d3.select('#piechart_container svg')
        .datum(datum)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .attr('height', 450)
        .call(chart);


    });



</script>


</head>
<body>
    <h1>tere</h1>

    <div id="piechart_container"><svg style="width:600px;height:400px;"></svg></div>
</body>
```

` 
 I've encountered a error like this yesterday when I was trying to use the nvd3 js library without django-nvd , anyways this is the last shot I'm giving to this library

UPDATE : I've tried using the demo django project provided in github's repo and same error still exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the developer merges [the pull request with this fix](https://github.com/areski/python-nvd3/pull/137), you may wish to update your requirements.txt to include this line:

-e git://github.com/aniketmaithani/python-nvd3#egg=python-nvd3

Answer (score 4):

`tooltipContent` was deprecated, and `tooltip` was moved into it's own object.

Use [`chart.tooltip.contentGenerator()`](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#tooltip), and pass in a function that builds the content.

Comment: the code was generated within nvd3-django module , I'll try to investigate how to fix this...

Answer (score 2):

To add up on cakan's answer and also to be specific. You need to edit these files by replacing 'chart.tooltipContent' with 'chart.tooltip.contentGenerator' on the corresponding line on the 'nvd3' module at the python site-packages.

1.) pythonx.x/site-packages/nvd3/templates/content.html at line '54' and '63'

2.) pythonx.x/site-packages/nvd3/templates/piechart.html at line '18'

Then just refresh or hard refresh your browser then the chart will appear

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this issue. Because django-nvd3 calls the functions and templates of python-nvd3(also the wrapper for python nvd3 developed by the same person).

The answer of liquidpele is completely right. You just need to replace all the functions `chart.tooltipContent` to `chart.tooltip.contentGenerator` in your python-nvd3 templates file (update files that call that function). This dictionary may appear in your python library installed location just like /lib/python2.7/sites-packages.

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit further? like which file are you going to replace and from which folder and which line?